# combine and count a json column in spark dataframe

Tags: sql, json, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to aggregate a column values (json) in spark dataframe and hive table.

e.g.

```
 year,   month,    val (json)
 2010    01        [{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"rgvtsa"},{"a_id":"btbsdv"}]
 2010    01        [{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"ohcwa"}]
 2008    10        [{"a_id":"rfve"},{"a_id":"yjndf"},{"a_id":"onbds"}]
 2008    10        [{"a_id":"fvds"},{"a_id":"yjndf"},{"a_id":"yesva"}]
```

I need:

```
 year,   month,    val (json),                                                          num (int)
 2010    01        [{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"rgvtsa"},{"a_id":"btbsdv},{"a_id":"uktf"}, {"a_id":"ohcwa"}]     5

 2008    10        [{"a_id":"rfve"},{"a_id":"yjndf"},{"a_id":"onbds"},{"a_id":"yesva"}]      4
```

I need to remove the duplicates and also find the size of the json string (num of "a_id") in it.

The data is saved as a hive table so it could be better to work on it by pyspark sql ?

I also would like to know how to work on it if it is saved as a spark dataframe.

I have tried:

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
 from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

 schema = StructType(
  [
    StructField('a_id', StringType(), True)
  ]
 )

 df.withColumn("val", from_json("val", schema))\
.select(col('year'), col('month'), col('val.*'))\
.show()
```

But, all values in "val1" are null.

thanks

**UPDTAE**
my hive  version:

```
%sh
 ls /databricks/hive | grep "hive"
 spark--maven-trees--spark_1.4_hive_0.13
```

My DDL:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T 
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def concate_elements(val):
   return reduce (lambda x, y:x+y, val)

flatten_array = F.udf(concate_elements, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

remove_duplicates = udf(lambda row: list(set(row)), 
ArrayType(StringType()))

#final results
df.select("year","month", flatten_array("val").alias("flattenvalues")).withColumn("uniquevalues", remove_duplicates("flattenvalues")).withColumn("size",F.size("uniquevalues")).show()
```

Comment: I read it from a string of json file & updated my answer, If you want to have a specific JSON in the val column and please update your question for reading a data( from hive or some other sources), since I tried my best to create DF with JSON/non-JSON columns but could not in a short while, if the provided answer is not solving your scenario then will look for some more options to solve your scnario.

Comment: updated the answer for your scenario -> reading data from hive in spark

Comment: Don't change your question frequently ask a New question instead??

Answer (score 0):

**considered input data input Json file `json-input.json`**

```
{"year":"2010","month":"01","value":[{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"ohcwa"}]}
{"year":"2011","month":"01","value":[{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"sathya"}]}
```

**Approach 1. Read data from hive**

**1. insert data into hive**

```
ADD JAR /home/sathya/Downloads/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE json_table (
year string,
month string,
value array<struct<a_id:string>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
load data local inpath '/home/sathya/json-input.json' into table json_table;

select * from json_table;
OK
2010    01  [{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"ohcwa"}]
2011    01  [{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"sathya"}]
```

**2. Read data from spark:**

```
pyspark --jars /home/sathya/Downloads/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar --driver-class-path  /home/sathya/Downloads/json-serde-1.3.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar

df=spark.sql("select * from default.json_table")
df.show(truncate=False)
'''
+----+-----+----------------------------------+
|year|month|value                             |
+----+-----+----------------------------------+
|2010|01   |[[caes], [uktf], [ohcwa]]         |
|2011|01   |[[caes], [uktf], [uktf], [sathya]]|
+----+-----+----------------------------------+
'''

#UDFs for concatenating the array elements & removing duplicates in an array

def concate_elements(val):
    return reduce (lambda x, y:x+y, val)

flatten_array = F.udf(concate_elements, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

remove_duplicates = udf(lambda row: list(set(row)), ArrayType(StringType()))

#final results
df.select("year","month",flattenUdf("value").alias("flattenvalues")).withColumn("uniquevalues", remove_duplicates("flattenvalues")).withColumn("size",size("uniquevalues")).show()

'''
+----+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+----+
|year|month|flattenvalues             |uniquevalues        |size|
+----+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+----+
|2010|01   |[caes, uktf, ohcwa]       |[caes, uktf, ohcwa] |3   |
|2011|01   |[caes, uktf, uktf, sathya]|[caes, sathya, uktf]|3   |
+----+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+----+

'''
```

**Approach 2 - direct read from input Json file `json-input.json`**

```
{"year":"2010","month":"01","value":[{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"ohcwa"}]}
{"year":"2011","month":"01","value":[{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"sathya"}]}
```

**code for your scenario is:**

```
import os
import logging 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

df=spark.read.json("file:///home/sathya/json-input.json")

df.show(truncate=False)
'''
+-----+----------------------------------+----+
|month|value                             |year|
+-----+----------------------------------+----+
|01   |[[caes], [uktf], [ohcwa]]         |2010|
|01   |[[caes], [uktf], [uktf], [sathya]]|2011|
+-----+----------------------------------+----+
'''

#UDFs for concatenating the array elements & removing duplicates in an array

def concate_elements(val):
    return reduce (lambda x, y:x+y, val)
 
flatten_array = F.udf(concate_elements, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

remove_duplicates = udf(lambda row: list(set(row)), ArrayType(StringType()))

#final results
df.select("year","month",flattenUdf("value").alias("flattenvalues")).withColumn("uniquevalues", remove_duplicates("flattenvalues")).withColumn("size",size("uniquevalues")).show()

'''
+----+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+----+
|year|month|flattenvalues             |uniquevalues        |size|
+----+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+----+
|2010|01   |[caes, uktf, ohcwa]       |[caes, uktf, ohcwa] |3   |
|2011|01   |[caes, uktf, uktf, sathya]|[caes, sathya, uktf]|3   |
+----+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+----+

'''
```

Comment: I have tried your "read data from spark", I got error: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6484.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6484.0 (TID 1089929, 10.71.184.24, executor 107): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 107 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
I run it on databricks.

Comment: Could you share me your hive ddl?? And what serre version you are using, it worked for me in my local

Comment: please see my updates in OP. Please let me know what is "serre" 
?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that'll work in Databricks:

```
#Import libraries

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#Define schema

schema1=StructType([
  StructField('year',IntegerType(),True),
  StructField('month',StringType(),True),
  StructField('val',ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField('a_id',StringType(),True)
  ])))
])

#Test data

rowsArr=[
  [2010,'01',[{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"rgvtsa"},{"a_id":"btbsdv"}]],
  [2010,'01',[{"a_id":"caes"},{"a_id":"uktf"},{"a_id":"ohcwa"}]],
  [2008,'10',[{"a_id":"rfve"},{"a_id":"yjndf"},{"a_id":"onbds"}]],
  [2008,'10',[{"a_id":"fvds"},{"a_id":"yjndf"},{"a_id":"yesva"}]]
]

#Create dataframe

df1=(spark
     .createDataFrame(rowsArr,schema=schema1)
    )

#Create database

spark.sql('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb')

#Dump it into hive table

(df1
 .write
 .mode('overwrite')
 .options(schema=schema1)
 .saveAsTable('testdb.testtable')
)

#read from hive table

df_ht=(spark
       .sql('select * from testdb.testtable')
      )

#Perform transformation

df2=(df_ht
     .groupBy('year','month')
     .agg(array_distinct(flatten(collect_list('val'))).alias('val'))
     .withColumn('num',size('val'))
    )
```

Input DF:

[image]

Output DF:

[image]